# Зачем нужна обработка исключений?

Tags: c++, исключения

Всю программистскую жизнь (примерно 1 год) меня мучает вопрос: зачем нужна обработка исключений? Разве трудно просто использовать условие?
Частый пример для использования исключений в учебниках (в моем случае по С++) - деление на нуль. Когда пользователь вводит 2 числа и, если второе (делитель) равен нулю, то выбрасывается исключение. Но зачем нужно это делать? Почему нельзя сразу вывести текст ошибки и закончить прогармму ( или передать вызывающему модулю)?

Answer (score 8):

По своему опыту могу предложить следующий взгляд на выбор варианта с использованием исключений:

**Везде, где это не обусловлено крайней необходимостью, НЕ стоит использовать исключения.**

Наиболее веские на то причины:

1. Исключения не предназначены для организации нормальных путей выполнения программы. Как пример, это усложняет задачу (или делает ее вообще практические невозможной) по предугадыванию пути выполнения программы (результат: branch miss predication). Сопровождать такой код становится также нетривиальной задачей.
2. Снижает быстродействие. Поддержка механизма исключения обходится не бесплатно, т.к. компиляторам приходится создавать доп. проверки и перехватчики исключений, поддерживать сами объекты исключений и пр. Это может особенно неожиданно "выстрелить" на какой-нибудь экзотической платформе в неподходящий момент.
3. Заранее возлагает на пользователя требование, чтобы он использовал механизм исключений для работы с вашим кодом.
4. Меж-модульное (т.е. за пределы бинарного модуля, например, DLL) прохождение исключений - плохая практика. Дело в том, что пользователь вместо перехвата по ссылке может использовать перехват *объекта исключения* по значению, что приведет к тому, что будет создаваться копия оригинального объекта исключения у клиента в совсем другом окружении. Кроме неэффективности, это еще и небезопасно.
5. Отсутствие понимания того, как этот механизм работает. Банально, но весьма жизненно.

*"Ну а когда же тогда их стоит использовать?"*

Исключения стоит использовать в следующих случаях:

1. Заранее известно, что ни в этом месте кода, ни в непосредственном клиенте невозможно корректно обработать серьезную ошибку. Тогда остается послать исключение "куда-повыше", в надежде, что "там" знают, что делать.
2. При необходимости уведомить клиента о невозможности корректно создать (инициализировать) объект - путем генерировании исключения в конструкторе. С другой стороны, можно инициализации объект с помощью, например, функции `Init()`, возвращающей код ошибки, и предоставить клиенту возможность самостоятельно решить, использовать ли ему исключения.

Comment: На пункты 4 и 5 нужно обратить особое внимание.

Comment: плюс к ответу. пример - работа с аппаратной частью, особенно в драйверах, когда бывают случаи "отказа" оборудования.

Answer (score 7):

Исключения являются одним из наиболее привлекательных средств языка. Нужно только научиться правильно ими пользоваться. Вопреки расхожему мнению, применение исключений намного шире, чем банальная обработка ошибок. Особенно удобно использовать их для передачи управления (а, возможно, и данных) сразу через несколько уровней в иерархии вызовов. Или даже не вызовов, а просто вложенных друг в друга блоков кода. Само название как бы намекает нам на то, что исключения предназначены для работы с исключительными ситуациями, которые вовсе не обязаны быть ошибочными. Они лишь должны быть исключительными по сравнению с обычным ходом выполнения программы. Настолько исключительными, чтобы не имело смысла каждый раз делать упреждающую проверку.

Comment: @Shamov, "Особенно удобно использовать их для передачи управления...", а longjmp() не балуетесь?

Вот с "Они лишь должны быть исключительными по сравнению..." согласен.

Comment: Нет, не балуюсь. Но на исключениях доводилось делать весьма нетривиальные вещи. Например, бросать исключение, на два уровня выше по иерархии самому его ловить, добавлять в него данные, которые известны только на этом уровне, и бросать исключение дальше, где оно потом окончательно ловится и обрабатывается.

Comment: Да, отличное средство, если надо написать код, в котором никто никогда не разберется.

Comment: Не разберётся в этом коде только тот, кто не разбирается в исключениях. И это скорее плюс, чем минус. Честно говоря, я не хочу, чтобы такие люди трогали мой код.

Comment: я когда-то писал парсер для самодельного языка. В модели с исключениями получилось очень красиво - парсер себе парсит рекурсивно. Если что то не так - бросает исключение. И оно по всей цепочке подымается вверх. А это десятки вложенных вызовов могут быть. Как бы делать этот код с кодами возвратов - смутно представляю.

Но вот делать код, который бросает исключения на каждом шаге - это уже не то. В некоторых компиляторах генерится такой код для исключений, что они могут убить всю производительность.

Comment: В одной конторе, где я работал, использовалась очень сложная самодельная библиотека, полностью построенная на кодах возврата. Множество этих кодов росло в геометрической прогрессии. Очень часто случалось такое, что системщики выпускали очередной релиз, и в changelog'е красовался один единственный пункт: добавлены новые ошибки. Имелись в виду новые коды возврата. Мы всё время радостно улыбались этой двусмысленной фразе. А однажды им пришлось добавить специальную функцию - erroneous_error(), которая возвращала true, если предыдущий код ошибки не следует считать ошибкой.

Comment: Все можно довести до абсурда.

Comment: Согласен. Но некоторые вещи доводятся до абсурда сами собой. Ну, не совсем сами собой, а в результате роста сложности системы. Вообще говоря, главный враг программиста - это сложность. Не в смысле difficulty, а в смысле complexity. И если не использовать самые передовые технологии борьбы со сложностью (напр. исключения), то рано или поздно комбинаторика обязательно побеждает любой человеческий разум. По какой-то злой иронии из этого правила исключений нет.

Comment: @Shamov, согласен с вами, что одна из главных бед - это неуправляемая сложность приложения, а еще и связность подсистем. Но исключения - это возможность, которую надо знать как применять, а также не стоит ее рассматривать как средство борьбы с плохим дизайном в целом. Сами по себе исключения "усложняют код", вводя отдельный механизм обработки и целый ряд ограничений.

Comment: @Shamov, вопрос только в том, что делают исключения? Упрощают алгоритмы или вносят дополнительную сложность? 

IMHO зависит от задачи.

Answer (score 6):

Допустимы оба подхода, но вариант с исключениями может быть элегантнее и компактнее.

Comment: Нужно смотреть на конкретные случаи.

С одной стороны, протаскивание кода ошибки через цепочку функций превратится в увлекательное занятие, которым лучше бы не заниматься. С другой, есть и такое:

    if (send_sms(msg) != OK) {
      if (send_email(msg) != OK) {
        notification_failed(msg);
      }
    }

Что с исключениями будет некрасивым

    try {
      send_sms(msg);
    } catch (DeliveryFailure e) {
      try {
        send_email(msg);
      } catch (DeliveryFailure e2) {
        notification_failed(msg);
      }
    }

(Кресты помню смутно, мог где-то затупить с синтаксисом.)

Comment: О чем и речь

Comment: Правильнее было бы так:

    try {
        send_sms(msg);
        send_email(msg);
    } catch (DeliveryFailure e) {
        notification_failed(msg);
    }

Плюс в том, что вы можете поймать исключения не только в блоке, где вызывали функцию.

ps. код не хочет вставать нормально в комментарии =(

Comment: Вот, кстати, один из немногих здесь толковых примеров, когда исключения на самом деле удобны.

Достаточно представить, что цепочка вызовов функций типа 

    send_sms(); send_email(); ... 

длинная и между вызовами есть код (например, подготовка аргументов), а при ошибке в любой из этих функций надо прекратить вызовы и выполнить единообразные действия. 

Вот тут обработка исключения действительно выглядит красиво.

Answer (score 5):

Можно. И более того - ест два больших лагеря программистов - одни считают что нужно делать исключения, другие - что только проверять код возврата.
В реальности, иногда невозможно проверить все условия и проще поставить обработку исключения - к примеру, если вызывается сторонний библиотечный код.

Также бывает, что если делать все проверки, то код превращается в набор проверок.

Comment: Мои программы строятся на огромном кол-ве функций. Я стараюсь делать так, чтобы при возникновении ошибки я мог спокойной поставить return и выйти из функции. Таким образом мне не нужны никакие исключения. Просто я думал, что не используя исключения я теряю важную штуку в прогарммировании.

Comment: @cheremushkin, скорее не теряете. Иногда исключения удобны, иногда приводят к нагромождению кода для проверок, что освобождать/закрывать. Собственно, последнее также нередко и при проверке кодов возврата.

Answer (score 4):

Исключения - это очень хорошо. В принципе, можно обойтись и без них и использовать стандартные коды возврата, но есть и неудобства в использовании кодов возврата.
 1. При использовании исключений практически гарантированно не будет проблем с временными объектами. Выкинули исключения - все недостроенные объекты грохнулись. И не нужно ломать голову какую память чистить итд.
 2. Если нужно передать информацию о проблемах при каскадном вызове функций с нижнего уровня на верхний проверка кодов возврата становится мучительной и очень громоздкой.

Comment: вопрос по п.1: Речь о генерировании исключения в конструкторе?

Answer (score 1):

Перешел на новую работу, там большое количество кода оказалось написано с использованием исключений. При попытке использовать код повторно, естественно они стали вылазить где не надо, и генерить ошибки. Пришлось переписывать старый код под обычные проверки.

Вообще мне исключения напоминают конструкцию goto, только еще хуже, т.к. передают управление на уровни выше. При большом количестве исключений, особенно если в разных местах генерятся одинаковые, отлаживать код ОЧЕНЬ сложно.

Comment: Выбор между плохим кодом с исключениями и хорошим кодом, где исключений нет, - это иллюзия. В действительности выбор всегда состоит в том, использовать ли для передачи управления на уровень выше (которую в любом случае нужно делать) специально предназначенные для этой цели исключения или же придумывать какие-то костыли с особыми кодами возврата, которые позволят проскочить сквозь несколько уровней иерархии.

Comment: В процессе перехода с исключений на коды возврата нужно постараться не допустить одну главную ошибку - не смешивать эти два способа в одном модуле.
С другой стороны - никто не мешает объектам, которые используются для исключений, добавить пару полей, которые будут нести дополнительную информацию. Но главный плюс исключений - это то, что многие компиляторы вставляют вывод стека вызовов, по которому можно проследить цепочку вызовов и выяснить, кто виноват в случае, если исключение не обработано. В случае, если исключение обработано на **высоком уровне**, стек может быть также интересен.

Comment: Что такое коды возврата? Просто какие-то свои коды и свои функции по которым можно что-то отследить?

Comment: коды возврата - это когда функция в случае успеха к примеру возвращает 0, а в случае ошибки - возвращает -1. Либо 0 в случае ошибки и позитивное число в случае успеха. Либо гарантирует, что выставит некую глобальную переменную в случае неудачи (`errno`).

Comment: Ситуации, когда в случае ошибки достаточно возвратить просто -1, очень просты. В таких случаях исключения можно и не использовать. И уж точно их нельзя оценить по достоинству, если имеешь дело только с такими случаями. Совсем другое дело, если в случае ошибки нужно передать наверх, например, имя файла. Причём в некоторых случаях оно должно быть абсолютным, а в некоторых - относительным. А ещё есть несколько случаев, когда передать нужно не только имя файла, но номер строки в этом файле.

Comment: А в чем тут принципиальная поблема? 

Возвращайте указатель на структуру, описывающую ошибку (в динамической памяти). По пути наверх в нее можно дописывать данные. Потом кто-то наверху ее должен освободить.

Comment: Принципиальной проблемы нет. Такое можно сделать даже на Си без всяких исключений. Просто С++ для таких случаев предоставляет механизм обработки исключений, как бы намекая на то, чтобы мы его использовали.

Comment: О чем и пишу. Кстати, у @nMike проблемы именно с исключениями при попытках повторного использования кода. 

IMHO это означает, что скорее всего обработку ошибок вообще не проектировали. В таком случаем переход на коды возврата тоже не поможет (те же яйца - вид сбоку), только "загонет болезнь вглубь".

Comment: И даже загнать болезнь вглубь ему будет намного проще, не уходя от исключений. Нужно всего лишь добавить всеобъемлющий catch(...) в функцию main(). И сразу все исключения перестанут вылазить "где не надо".

Comment: И что дальше с ними делать в main()? Красиво завершиться?