# Что дешевле: словить исключение или отправить запрос в бд?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, исключения

Есть функция, которая добавляет информацию в бд. Функция может отправить запрос в бд для предварительной проверки, возможно ли добавить сущность, либо просто словить исключение.

Первый вариант (проверяем есть ли такое имя пользователя в бд, не ловим исключение):

```
    public virtual async Task<ServiceResult> CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        var errors = Validation(user);
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            return new ServiceResult(false, errors);
        }

        if (await Queryable.AnyAsync(u => u.UserName == user.UserName))
        {
            return new ServiceResult(false, "This username already exists.");
        }

        try
        {
            await DbContext.AddAsync(user);
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ServiceResult(false, ex.Message);
        }

        return new ServiceResult(true);
    }
```

Второй вариант (не проверяем есть ли такое имя пользователя в бд, ловим исключение):

```
    public virtual async Task<ServiceResult> CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        var errors = Validation(user);
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            return new ServiceResult(false, errors);
        }

        try
        {
            await DbContext.AddAsync(user);
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ServiceResult(false, ex.Message);
        }

        return new ServiceResult(true);
    }
```

Какой способ оптимальней?

Comment: Имхо, при вставке есть та же самая проверка на уникальность, поэтому лучше делать один запрос, а не два. Стоимость исключения ерунда в сравнении со стоимостью отправки запроса по сети

Comment: А вы считаете, что при обращении к БД исключение может возникнуть только при нарушении уникальности ключа при вставке? Отвалилась сеть во время запроса - исключение; запрос повис на каком-нибудь длинном локе - исключение. Продолжать? Вам в любом случае необходимо обрабатывать эти исключения. Плюс не забывайте, что между вашими двумя запросами другой клиент вполне может успеть выполнить вставку и вы опять же получите исключение.

Comment: Ни кто так ни чего и не написал за два года =( перенесу в ответ расширенную версию комментария.

Comment: И то, и другой бесплатно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Исключения при работе с базой данных нужно обрабатывать всегда, т.к. причиной исключения может быть не только существование записи, которую вы пытаетесь добавить, но и много других факторов, таких как отвалившийся канал связи, долгая блокировка и вылет по тайм-ауту и т.д. и т.п. К тому же, между выполнением проверки существования записи и вставкой записи достаточный промежуток времени, чтобы между этими событиями другой клиент успел выполнить свою вставку и вы получите тоже самое исключение даже без прочих внешних факторов.
2. В SQL для безопасной вставки можно использовать инструкцию `MERGE` вместо `INSERT`. EF тоже предоставляет механизм безопасного добавления в виде метода [AddOrUpdate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate?view=entity-framework-5.0.0), но я не смотрел, как он работает внутри, да и он менее гибок чем MERGE, т.к. реализует всего одну из возможностей использования MERGE. Например, с помощью MERGE я могу просто ничего не выполнять, если запись уже существует.

Answer (score -2):

1. Если доступ к СУБД правильно организован, то последовательные запросы к БД выполняются в рамках одного подключения к СУБД, что приводит к быстрым откликам. 
   Напротив, генерация и обработка исключений - это дорогие операции, включающие хитрую работу со стеком вызовов. Поэтому нужно минимизировать шанс возникновения исключения с помощью валидации.
2. Валидация входных данных - это нормальная часть бизнес-логики. Чтобы отказываться от валидации обычно нужны веские причины. 
   Исключения же не должны являться частью бизнес-логики, чаще всего они сообщают о системных сбоях, которые проявляются редко.
3. Валидация не поможет в редком случае, когда действия нескольких пользователей пересекаются на уровне строк таблицы. Для решения подобных проблем существует механизм транзакций. Вот здесь уже без обработки исключения завершения транзакции не обойтись. На то он и исключительный случай.

Можно также прочесть более развёрнутый ответ об исключениях:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/140607/242690